# Fundamental Architecture of an iPhone App: what does exactly happen?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am new to iPhone-Programming and I am probably asking a beginner's question, but I really couldn't find a satisfying answer to this:

I would like to understand the underlying architecture or structure of an iPhone App. What comes first, what are the parts that a starting template usually does automatically?  In C-Programms, you know the program always jumps into main and then everything starts like you coded it. In iPhone-Programming, we start also in main and then something like the event loop starts and etc.there is a lot going on under hood, which I would like to understand so I feel more confident writing code and actually being aware of all consequences that my code causes.

I would be happy about any answers or are there any good references that are compact and only focussed on the coding architecture?

Comment: Did u see the iOS application programming guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html  ??

Comment: Yes I have. You are right, everything I need to know is on this webpage. The thing is I was overwhelmed by the amount of information, I found it difficult to see where to start. I wanted more a small top-down explanation I can start from and I don't get lost in detail. I should have pointed that out more clearly in the question I guess. The answer and link by RobertVojta is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this for example ... http://www.technolike.com/archives/86/core-application-architecture-for-iphone.html ... and Google for more. There are many resources how to iPhone application starts, what's going under the hood, how event handling cycle does work, etc. Also when you read these resources, try to ask more specific questions. It's too broad question to answer everything.

Comment: This is a great document to start with, I know the question is broad and because it's general I wanted to start with an overview before I get lost in the documentation. Too bad the links are outdated, but I will try to find corresponding one's in the apple documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you browse through Apple's documentation on iOS development: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

If you want to learn the low level stuff first, perhaps you should look into how `Objective C` works and then move to learn about `UIKit` (which is the central framework/library for iOS app development).